# Passing an object to console.warn causing error in react-native

Tags: reactjs, function, react-native, console

When I am passing object to `console.warn` like

```
console.warn({"1": "cool"})
```

it is throwing following error

`argument[0].indexOf is not a function`

But on passing string it is working fine like

```
console.warn("some text")
```

As mentioned [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_warn.asp), it should accept both string and object.

> String or Object

Answer (score 1):

`console.warn` messages in React Native are shown in the native app with [YellowBox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#warnings). YellowBox can only display strings, not objects.

If you only want to see warnings when debugging the app with the remote debugger, you can disable YellowBox with `console.disableYellowBox = true;`. You can then use `console.warn` with objects as well, but then you won't see any warnings in the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to specific console implementation. w3schools.com cannot be used as reliable source of information. According to the specification, console methods [can accept objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/warn) but it's unnecessary that console implementation follows the specification.

The error suggests that this console implementation expected an argument to be an array for some reason, possibly because it was identified as array-like object.

A safer way that is compatible with different console implementations is to output a string:

```
console.warn(JSON.stringify({"1": "cool"}, null, 2))
```

Comment: The actual specification link is https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-console-warn-data-data